# Applescript Progress bar sticks after steps completed

Tags: applescript, progress-bar

The following example works great, however after the total steps are reached, the progress dialog stays visible behind the next dialog box that shows. Is this expected behaviour and if so, is there anyway to hide it on completion?

```
set progress description to "A simple progress indicator"
set progress additional description to "Preparing…"
set progress total steps to -1

delay 5

set progress total steps to 100
repeat with i from 1 to 100
    try
        set progress additional description to "I am on step " & i
        set progress completed steps to i
        delay 0.2
    on error thisErr
        display alert thisErr
        exit repeat
    end try
end repeat
```

Comment: I use same script almost with ElCapitain since few months and dialog progress bar closed automatically when reaching step 100. Are you using new Sierra ?

Comment: Nope im on el capitan!

Comment: I copy/paste your script without any change, save it as an application on desktop and run it. Progress bar window disappear as expected at the end, when application is foreground more or background mode. I also run ElCapitain 10.11.6 ( build 15G1217). Sorry I can't help more

Comment: Try running a normal dialog box after and see if it still disappears?